Use rigid body physics with python
I want to drop a sphere into a curved pipe and have it bounce along the edges realistically but does not come to a stop.

I tried using rigid body but the ball comes to rest after a bit. I played around with the settings and there are tradeoffs and nothing really works for my use case. If I reduce the substeps and solver iterations then the ball does not come to a stop but the bounces become unrealistic after a while. If I increase the substeps and solver iterations then the bounces are realistic but the ball comes to a stop.
Is there a way I can leverage rigid body collision detection and use python to animate this? For example:
1. Give an initial velocity to sphere using python (I'm able to do that)
2. Detect if it hits the pipe using python (Need help with this part)
3. If it hit the pipe get the normal at the point of contact using python (Need help with this part)
4. Reflect the velocity along the normal using python (I'm able to do that)
5. Repeat

I'm open to exploring other approaches as well.

This is more suitable for geometry nodes. Python control is limited to frame-change handlers and I think you would have to write an entire physics system for this. Check out cartesian caramel on gumroad, he has free geo nodes of rigid body physics. But also, your question doesn't make sense to me, what do you mean about it coming to a stop. Could you link a video of what's happening so we can see what it is you don't want to happen? If you want the ball to keep moving forever, maybe move the pipe in a circular motion for forever (cycles modifier on f-curve)

Let me make a video and get back here.
